# Merge sublist if condition is true

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, merge, conditional-statements

Example:

```
mylist = [['2', '12/12/2016'], ['4', '10/12/2016'], ['5', '08/12/2016'], ['4', '10/12/2016'], ['7', '12/12/2016'], ['10', '12/12/2016'], ['11', '08/12/2016'], ['4', '12/12/2016'], ['10', 'test']]
```

The 1st element in the sublist is a string number
The 2nd element in the sublist can be whatever string

I want to merge the sublists if the first element in a sublist is already in the list (and remove the strings who are double)

Output:

```
newlist = [['2', '12/12/2016'], ['4', '10/12/2016', '12/12/2016'], ['5', '08/12/2016'], ['7', '12/12/2016'], ['10', '12/12/2016', 'test'], ['11', '08/12/2016']]
```

How can I obtain a merged list based on a condition?

Comment: I feel like a dictionary would be handy in this situation

Comment: Does the ordering of the result matter?

Comment: @niemmi, yes the ordering matters

Comment: So what is the correct order?

Comment: `defaultdict` (but it's not ordered)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to keep both ordering of the sublists and items within the sublists as close to original as possible you could utilize [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

mylist = [['2', '12/12/2016'], ['4', '10/12/2016'], ['5', '08/12/2016'],
          ['4', '10/12/2016'], ['7', '12/12/2016'], ['10', '12/12/2016'],
          ['11', '08/12/2016'], ['4', '12/12/2016'], ['10', 'test']]

res = OrderedDict()
for s1, s2 in mylist:
    res.setdefault(s1, OrderedDict())[s2] = True

res = [[k] + list(v) for k, v in res.items()]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[['2', '12/12/2016'], ['4', '10/12/2016', '12/12/2016'], ['5', '08/12/2016'], 
 ['7', '12/12/2016'], ['10', '12/12/2016', 'test'], ['11', '08/12/2016']]
```

Above constructs `OrderedDict` where keys are first elements from the lists and values are `OrderedDict` objects. Second level dicts contain the second elements from lists as keys. Second level values are irrelevant, `OrderedDict` is only used because Python standard library doesn't have `OrderedSet`.

**Update**: Assuming that

1. Sublists have third element which is list of two numbers
2. Result list should be ordered based on first occurrence of first element
3. Sublists should contain only unique pairs and be ordered based on the first number of the pair

You could use `set` on second level and sort the pairs when constructing result:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

mylist = [['1', 'string1', [22,25]], ['4', 'string1', [12,19]], 
          ['4', 'string3', [48,53]], ['8', 'string3', [14,19]],
          ['4', 'string3', [48,53]]]

res = OrderedDict()
for s, _, l in mylist:
    res.setdefault(s, set()).add(tuple(l))

res = [[k] + sorted(v) for k, v in res.items()]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[['1', (22, 25)], ['4', (12, 19), (48, 53)], ['8', (14, 19)]]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. The ordering is ascending (by 1st element of sublist), as in your answer.

Comment: niemmi, I still have not totally resolved my problem. If mylist = `[['1', 'string1', [22-25]], ['4', 'string1', [12-19]], ['4', 'string3', [48-53]], ['8', 'string3', [14-19]]]` - The same as above in my question, what would be the output if I don't want the strings to be added but the stringplaces (stringplaces ordered ascending)? Expected output: `[['1', [22-25]], ['4', [12-19], [48-53]], ['8', [14-19]]]`

Comment: @Reman What is `[22-25]`? Is it a `list` containing all the integers in the range as in `[22, 23, 24, 25]`? Would all the third items in the sublists have the same type?

Comment: Niemmi, [22-25] ==> [startcolumn-endcolumn]

Comment: @Reman Start column and end column of what? Can you give literal example of input and expected out? Unless the input is `[['1', 'string1', [-3]],...]` and output respectively `[['1', [-3]], ...]`

Comment: You're right. It is the start and end column of the string in my text line (consider it as slices in a string). Please see my 2nd comment for an eample, Ordering ascending means [12-19][48-53][62-76] etc. Thanks niemmi!

Comment: @Reman I'm still not 100% sure we're on the same page but I updated the solution based on what I think you're asking.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this code, but return not oredered list:

```
result = [[x] + [y[1]
             for y in filter(lambda z: z[0] == x, mylist)]
      for x in set(map(lambda q: q[0], mylist))]
```

Comment: You can order `result` with: `ordered_result = sorted(result, key=lambda l: int(l[0]),reverse=False)`

Answer (score 1):

This could probably be made into a generator expression, but written out simply, this approach should work...

```
new_list = []
for number, date in mylist:
    for index, item in enumerate(new_list):
        if item[0] == number:
            if date not in item:
                new_list[index].append(date)
            break
    else:
        new_list.append([number, date])
```

Output:

```
[['2', '12/12/2016'],
 ['4', '10/12/2016', '12/12/2016'],
 ['5', '08/12/2016'],
 ['7', '12/12/2016'],
 ['10', '12/12/2016', 'test'],
 ['11', '08/12/2016']]
```

Though, as mentioned, an OrderedDict, perhaps using the `setdefault` method may be a more apt solution, since dictionary keys are unique.

edit: tweaked to remove dups

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate solution to @niemmi you can use this, which also uses `OrderDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

mylist = [['2', '12/12/2016'], ['4', '10/12/2016'], ['5', '08/12/2016'], 
['4', '10/12/2016'], ['7', '12/12/2016'], ['10', '12/12/2016'], 
['11', '08/12/2016'], ['4', '12/12/2016'], ['10', 'test']]

res = OrderedDict((key, []) for key in [tup[0] for tup in mylist])
for tup in mylist:
    if tup[1] not in res[tup[0]]:
        res[tup[0]].append(tup[1])
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another regular and straight forward and easy to understand example is:

```
mylist = [['2', '12/12/2016'], ['4', '10/12/2016'], ['5', '08/12/2016'], \
         ['4', '10/12/2016'], ['7', '12/12/2016'], ['10', '12/12/2016'], \
         ['11', '08/12/2016'], ['4', '12/12/2016'], ['10', 'test']]
d = dict()

for sublist in mylist:
    indx = sublist[0]
    if indx in d.keys():
        d[indx].append(sublist[1])
    else:
        d[indx] = sublist

res = []
for key,value in d.iteritems():
    res.append(value)

print sorted(res, key=lambda l: int(l[0]),reverse=False)
```

Output:

```
[['2', '12/12/2016'], ['4', '10/12/2016', '10/12/2016', '12/12/2016'], 
['5', '08/12/2016'], ['7', '12/12/2016'], ['10', '12/12/2016', 'test'], 
['11', '08/12/2016']]
```